# Error with mongodb on mac permission denied

Tags: mongodb, macos, error-handling, terminal

Hi I have problem when I run

```
mongod
```

This is what I got

```
2016-02-09T21:54:40.631-0700 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /data/db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.

2016-02-09T21:54:40.633-0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 98 Unable to create/open lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
2016-02-09T21:54:40.633-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100
```

I try everything uninstall mongo. Install with brew. Uninstall with brew etc. Change the permission of my data folder and get always the same problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So this is what I did. I delete the /data/db folder after a recreate it with

```
sudo mkdir -p /data/db
```

Change the permission of data and db folder

```
mongod
```

everything working. My error was I didn't change the permission before I run mongod for the first time now everything is working fine.

Comment: I know this is old, but on newer macs it's changed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58283257/mongodb-cant-find-data-directory-after-upgrading-to-mac-os-10-15-catalina

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same issues until I ran

`sudo chown -R 'youruserid' /data/db`

it seems some file(s) in the directory still had the wrong permissions.

Answer (score 4):

I think I had a similar problem with my mongo install in my Mac. Have you tried changing the owner of /db/data?

You can check who owns this directory (where the databases are stored) by writing the following command in the terminal.

```
ls -al /data/db
```

If the owner (the name in the third column) is not your user, change it with a *chown* command or try running *mongod* with sudo.

Comment: `2016-02-09T22:50:54.575-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000`

Comment: If you are using mongo on your Mac for development purposes, then it's ok. You can check more at https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/ulimit/

Comment: I still suggest you change the owner of the /data/db directory. I do not recommend having to use sudo when you run the mongod command.

Answer (score 0):

I would first check to see if you have another instance of mongo running as it suggests.  If you do not - remove the lock file in question and try to launch mongo again.  It is possible the lock file is a remnant of a previous install.

Comment: I try to find if another instance is running but didn't find nothing

Comment: Ok - so remove the lock file and try to start mongo.

Comment: Done and the samething is wrote in the console

Comment: I check all my running program with 'top' and didnt find nothing about mongo

Comment: What kind of machine are on .. just curious.. Have you checked the permission of the dir in question /data/db

Comment: So did the lock file exist in that location?  If not, it could just be you need to make sure the mongo user has access to that dir..maybe with something like: chown mongodb:mongodb -R /data/db

Comment: macbook pro when I 'ps aux | grep mongod' i see 6706   0.0  0.0  2444056    792 s003  S+   10:49pm   0:00.00 grep mongod

Comment: I think you have a permission issue - You need to do a chown on the /data/db dir to give mongo permission to that dir.

Answer (score -1):

1. `systemctl enable mongod.service`
   Start mongod service at system startup
2. `service mongod start`

Comment: This is not a correct answer. `systemctl` and `service` have nothing to do with permission issues.