# MongoDB can't find data directory after upgrading to Mac OS 10.15 (Catalina)

Tags: mongodb, macos

I updated to MacOS 10.15 (Catalina) today. When I run `mongod` in the terminal it cannot find the `/data/db` directory:

```
➜  /Users/william > mongod
2019-10-08T17:02:44.183+0800 I CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2019-10-08T17:02:44.209+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=43162 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=Williams-MacBook-Pro-6.local
2019-10-08T17:02:44.209+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.0.3
2019-10-08T17:02:44.209+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 7ea530946fa7880364d88c8d8b6026bbc9ffa48c
2019-10-08T17:02:44.209+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2019-10-08T17:02:44.209+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2019-10-08T17:02:44.209+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2019-10-08T17:02:44.209+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2019-10-08T17:02:44.209+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2019-10-08T17:02:44.209+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2019-10-08T17:02:44.211+0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/db not found., terminating
2019-10-08T17:02:44.211+0800 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2019-10-08T17:02:44.211+0800 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2019-10-08T17:02:44.211+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2019-10-08T17:02:44.211+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
➜  /Users/william >
```

I tried to install MongoDB with `brew`:

```
brew install mongodb

➜  /Users/william > brew install mongodb
Updating Homebrew...
Error: mongodb: unknown version :mountain_lion
```

Any help?

Answer (score 140, accepted):

This is the main error:

> exception in initAndListen: NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/db not found., terminating

Catalina has a surprise change: it won't allow changes to the root directory (this was discussed in a [forum thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/mongodb/comments/d7takd/macos_x_catalina_105_beta_and_mongo_a_warning/) as well):

```
% sudo mkdir -p /data/db
mkdir: /data/db: Read-only file system
```

Unfortunately, this is not spelled out explicitly in Apple's [Catalina release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos_release_notes/macos_catalina_10_15_release_notes), other than a brief mention in [Catalina features](https://www.apple.com/macos/catalina/features/):

> macOS Catalina runs in a dedicated, read-only system volume

Since the directory `/data/db` is coded as MongoDB default, a workaround is to specify a different `dbpath` that is not located on the root directory. For example:

```
mongod --dbpath ~/data/db
```

This will place MongoDB's data in your home directory. Just make sure that the path `~/data/db` actually exists.

**Alternative method**

An alternative method is to follow the instructions at [Install MongoDB Community Edition on macOS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/) by leveraging `brew`:

```
brew tap mongodb/brew
brew install mongodb-community
```

This will create some additional files by default:

- the configuration file (/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf)
- the log directory path (/usr/local/var/log/mongodb)
- the data directory path (/usr/local/var/mongodb)

To run `mongod` you can either:

- Run the command manually from the command line (this can be aliased for convenience):

  ```
  mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf
  ```
- Run MongoDB as a service using `brew services`. Note that this will run MongoDB as a standalone node (not a replica set), so features that depends on the oplog e.g. changestreams will not work unless you modify the `mongod` configuration file:

  ```
  brew services start mongodb-community
  ```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, any methods to configure dbpath in bash_profile? so that, there is no need for running mongod with db path every time.

Comment: I guess, after the update, OS deleted /data/db folder which was present under mongodb

Comment: @MadhavanSundararaj if you want to run `mongodb --dbpath ...` by just typing `mongod` in bash, you can use an alias like `alias mongod='mongod --dbpath ...'` and put that alias in your `bashrc`. It's not the cleanest solution but it might work for your purposes.

Comment: isn't the latest macOS uses zsh? if so, does it still use .bashrc. Because the above suggested alias did not work as expected

Comment: @MadhavanSundararaj for `zsh` or any other shell, you need to put the alias under that shell's rc file. For `zsh` it's `~/.zshrc`. Make sure you also follow the shell's syntax on creating aliases as well.

Comment: It seems if i use `brew services start mongodb-community` it cant read `dbpath` variable from config. `mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf` works correctly

Comment: @l2ysho if you're having issues starting the brew service, do you mind creating an issue at https://github.com/mongodb/homebrew-brew and describe what error you're seeing?

Comment: `brew services start mongodb-community` doesn’t read the dbPath config correctly. Once I run the command with sudo, everything works!

Answer (score 84):

After installing Catalina, you might have a folder on your Desktop called `Relocated Items`. You can find the `data/db` folder inside the `Security` folder.

All I had to do was move the `Security/data/db`, specifically `data/db` and place it inside my home folder.

You can do this with the Finder app or with the terminal by running the following command:

```
sudo mv /Users/Shared/Relocated\ Items/Security/data ~/
```

After that run:
`mongod --dbpath ~/data/db`

It's up to you to create the alias

Comment: I almost went insane that Catalina upgrade could have erased all my data. Thanks for saving me from the madness!

Comment: When I run the mongod command I get: “mongod” cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified.

Comment: @Raz: I think this is related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/362883/mongodb-doesnt-work-after-update-to-macos-catalina-10-15

Comment: Worked for me, this is much better solution.

Comment: This is definitely the most complete solution

Answer (score 15):

[Kevinadi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5619724/kevinadi) already did justice to the question, however this is how I went about solving the problem:

After installing mongodb-community

1. `sudo mkdir -p /System/Volumes/Data/data/db` (Create the data/db folder)
2. `sudo chown -R`id -un`/System/Volumes/Data/data/db` (Give permissions)
3. `mongod --dbpath=/System/Volumes/Data/data/db` (Change dbpath of mongodb)
4. `mongod` (Runs well)

I found this [article](https://zellwk.com/blog/install-mongodb/) on installing mongodb very useful

Comment: This helped after 1 day of trying to fix the problem! The article doesn't mention changing dbpath and that's what I was missing

Comment: This returns a new, different error for me: `aborting after fassert() failure` 

Answer (score 1):

found a trick...
delete the ~/data/db entire folder from the directory
then recreate a new one but DO NOT USE mkdir -p /data/db
instead, just use your trackpad to do it
[use system way to create folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aF7tn.png)

this worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me:

1. Create a folder somewhere e.g. Development/mongodb/data/db
2. Open *mongod.conf* file and update *storage.dbPath* value to the the newly created folder path

Comment: where is the mongod.conf file??

Comment: It is the default file.

Go to this link: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/  and then to "Configuration File"

Answer (score 1):

Mac version Catalina made the root folder is no longer writable.

Brew has an updated version of mongodb to use a new path (which it creates itself), `/usr/local/var/mongodb` and following these instructions will fix the issue:

[Guide to installing updated mongodb-community-edition](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/#install-mongodb-community-edition)

`brew install mongodb-community@VERSION` where the first VERSION with the fix is 4.2

Comment: The above command should be executed with sudo. Then the dbPath config will be respected. Otherwise mongo still defaults to `/data/db` regardless of the config.

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the same problem with BigSur and unfortunately Relocated Items folder didn't contain anything looking like my MongoDB dump. I decided to search Finder by database name, as dump contains folders with database names. And my dump turned out to be here

**Macintosh HD/System/Volumes/Macintosh HD/data/db**

As far as I understood the dump had been moved on the sly during OS update because it used to be at root and now OS does not give permission to write to root.

Answer (score 0):

Your docker image will be able to find your directories regardless of where they are if you use relative directory references ~/Desktop will map your Mac Desktop directory into your image as /Desktop.

```
docker run -it -v ~/Desktop:/Desktop r-base bash
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to `~/Users/Shared` folder.
here, you will find a folder titled 'Relocated items' inside that you will be able to find a 'data' folder.This 'data folder contains your mongodb database in`/data/db'.

Now, copy this 'data' folder and paste it in your `Users/<name-of-your-user-account-with-the-home-icon">`.

And now open zsh terminal and run `mongod --dbpath ~/data/db` and now open a new  shell in a separate  tab and type `mongo` to open the mongo shell and you will be good to go.

**Remember** to use `mongod --dbpath ~/data/db` each time while running mongod or make an alias.

Answer (score 0):

For me after the Catalina upgrade it moved to a different folder than mentioned above. In case anyone finds the same path, you can use the below solution.

```
cp /Users/Shared/Previously\ Relocated\ Items/Security/data ~
mongod --dbpath ~/data/db
```

This way you can see your old databases and collections when you access mongo shell using

```
mongo
show dbs
```