# MongoDB doesn't run after switching from bash to zsh

Tags: mongodb, macos, zsh, server-side

I apologize if this has somehow been answered. But, I have been stuck on this for awhile now to the point where I am losing hope in using a local server (MongoDB). I am also a person simply learning all of this, so please forgive me if I am asking a "noob" question.

---

**Setup:** MacOS using iTerm, using brew.

---

**Problem:**

Was able to use MongoDB fine when I was using the bash shell. No problems at all.

---

**Issue:**

macOS forced me to switch to `zsh` shell and now, I can't run it.

[after running mongod](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2Mkv.png)

The error message shows that I do not have the directory `/data/db`. I saw that others had the same problem.

---

**What I have already tried:**

- reinstalling brew
- reinstalling MongoDB
- `mkdir -p /data/db`
- switching path to the said directory

None seem to work. In fact, when I try to make `/data/db`, it states that it is a read-only file as follows.

[after running mkdir -p /data/db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7aNX.png)

Please help me :(

Comment: When I use mongo I put the data in a local folder to the project, which you can git ignore if you like. I like having projects encapsulated and not leaving ghost data around on my PC. Have you tried having a local data path?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have seen posts about creating local data paths, but have not tried it. I have seen that they are "not good"? Is that not true? Also, I am assuming local data path as in "create a data folder in the project and link it"? I have no idea how I'd do that, but I can try.

Comment: You can do it like this: `mongod --dbpath=./localdata`. I only start a mongo instance during development, when the app is deployed I just connect to a running service so I can't see how it's bad practice.

Comment: alright, I can run the above now with a localdata folder that I created. Is there anyway it defaults to that path while running *mongod*? or do I have to type in the whole thing (mongod --dbpath=./localdata) everytime?

Comment: I have it as a NPM package.json script with the arg so depends how you're running it. You could set an `alias` in the terminal but would only apply for you

Comment: P.S. If you prefer the data in your home directory it should work too - `--dbpath ~/data/db`. I run it per project as an NPM script so localdata works for me

Comment: Alright, for now, I will run it with the specified dbpath. Thanks so much for taking the time to enlighten me. I am excited to move forward with node. Thanks again!

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58283257/mongodb-doesnt-work-on-latest-mac-os10-15