# Trying to specify a db path for mongodb

Tags: mongodb, terminal, macos-catalina

I am following this thread ([MongoDB can't find data directory after upgrading to Mac OS 10.15 (Catalina)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58283257/mongodb-cant-find-data-directory-after-upgrading-to-mac-os-10-15-catalina)). When I hit the command mongod --dbpath ~/data/db Terminal stalls on this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hOwp.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39Fjk.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that mongo isn't being blocked by "Security and Privacy" - take a look in system preferences - security and privacy - privacy. You might need to grant it access to the filesystem

Comment: Hi Steven, thanks for the response. Mongodb wasn't mentioned in any of the privacy tabs and I 'ticked' all the ones giving access permission to Terminal. No effect I'm afraid.